# MySQL: Get Row Size by Column

Tags: mysql, size, row

I tried to alter one column in an existing table, from `Varchar(5000)` to `Varchar(10000)` using SQLyog.

This resulted in an error:

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not
>   counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the
>   manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs.

I understand from this forum that I need to change this large `Varchar` field to Text - which I assume is stored 'outside' of the table in `Innodb` - but I would be interested in seeing a list of all columns for the table and the size they use.

Can anyone suggest a query etc, that could do this?

Answer (score 3):

Look into information_schema.COLUMNS table, it has lot of such details.

This is query for getting varchar columns and their length for any table-

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS AS ins
WHERE ins.TABLE_NAME = '<your table name>' AND ins.DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
```

Comment: You can try this if you want **sum up** of all columns with _data type = varchar_ : `SELECT table_schema, DATA_TYPE, count(column_name) as column_count, 
 sum(character_maximum_length)
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' AND table_schema = database() 
GROUP BY table_schema;`

Answer (score 0):

To see a list of all columns for the table and the size they use, you can run:

```
describe my_table;
```

Or to see the create table statement:

```
show create table my_table;
```

Comment: I don't understand the size shown by DESCRIBE. The varchar(5000) column shows "13B", which is the same for a column of varchar(2000)?